# How to show an alert dialog anywhere in my application?

Tags: java, android

I have an android application where on BaseActivity, I need to check for some logic and trigger to show an alert dialog irrespective of the Activity opened. It means, no matter which activity class I am in, the alert dialog should show up on top of that activity.

Making sure that, all my activities extends BaseActivity.

Below, is my function to show alert dialog

```
if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("There is some unsynced data. Please connect it to internet and sync it. The user will be logged out if data is not synced for 72 hours")
                .setTitle("Attention")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", listener);
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG);
        dialog.show();
    }


android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3822)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3854)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:798)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
    at com.gmp_manage_v2.ui.activities.BasePrinterActivity.showAlertToSyncData(BasePrinterActivity.java:463)
    at com.gmp_manage_v2.ui.activities.BasePrinterActivity.onResume(BasePrinterActivity.java:304)
    at com.gmp_manage_v2.ui.activities.ActiveSessionListActivity.onResume(ActiveSessionListActivity.java:470)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7300)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3814)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3854) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: What prevents you to put a dialog into BaseActivity ?

Comment: Add a method to create and show dialog in base activity.

Comment: I did the same. But, the activity from where it's getting triggered, is not longer active. Then I am getting an exception and an error message that "is the activity still running?" @Rohit5k2

Comment: @blackkara Same answer for you

Comment: show how you are triggering dialog and please post your logcat also

Comment: @AndroDuster: You shall have to show code and logcat log

Comment: @TejasPandya Added code snippet

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Added code snippet

Comment: @AndroDuster How about you can generate a Util class and show alert message from it?

Comment: Same error @ND1010_

Comment: @AndroDuster Post your code please , what did you have change

Comment: @AndroDuster It's worth to consider, you should also check for devices that api's above 17 with `isDestroyed()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use current activity context rather than Application context.

Change

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat)
```

to

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.Theme_AppCompat)
```

`getApplicationContext()` can be used only if you are using `dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)` with permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

Comment: **Still the same error** isn't the right response. Please explain and post the code you changed.

Comment: I removed "dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)" and changed getApplicationContext() to this (activity context). I behaving as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: Okay! Sorry my bad! Thanks anyways!